# JQuery find style with rgb to replace with hex color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on my jquery script to find the style with the color and the rgb that I want to find to replace it with `#444444`. I have got a problem with find the style color because when I try this:

```
$('#text_editor').find('[style*="color: rgb(68, 68, 68)]"').css('color', '#444444');
```

It wont let me to find the style with the color and rgb as it wont replace it.

I have also tried this:

```
$('#text_editor').find('color: rgb(68, 68, 68)').css('color', '#444444');
```

And this:

```
document.execCommand('foreColor', false, '#444444');
$('#text_editor').find("span[style*='color: rgb(68, 68, 68)']").css('color', '#444444');
```

It make no different as I am keep getting this:

```
<span style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68);">sdgsdgsdgsdgsdg</span>
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
<span style="color: #444444;">sdgsdgsdgsdgsdg</span>
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="text_editor" class="editor_message" hidefocus="false" aria-label="Message Body" g_editable="true" role="textbox" aria-hidden="true" aria-multiline="true" contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" style="direction: ltr; height: 500px; width: 100%; padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 18px; font-size: 16px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d1d1; border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1; border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d1; overflow-y: auto;" itacorner="6,7:1,1,0,0">
    <span style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68);">sdgsdgsdgsdgsdg</span>
</div>
```

Here is the full code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#color-picker1', function(e) {

    $('#color-picker' + colorpicker_number + ' div').removeClass('tick-color');
    $('#color-picker' + colorpicker_number).removeClass('color-picker-border');
    $('#color-picker1 div').addClass('tick-color');
    $('#color-picker1').addClass('color-picker-border');
    colorpicker_number = 1;
    alert("time to change the color 6");
    document.execCommand('styleWithCSS', 0, true);
    document.execCommand('foreColor', false, '#444444');
    $('#text_editor').find('[style*="color: rgb(68, 68, 68)"]').css('color', '#444444');

    if ($('#toolbar_text_color').css('display') == 'block') {
        $('#toolbar_text_color').hide();
    }
    $('#text_editor').focus();
});
```

Can you please show me an example how I can find the style with the rgb color that I want to find before I could use css to replace it with `#444444`?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery find span style color to replace with color hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59571573/jquery-find-span-style-color-to-replace-with-color-hash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it wont change if you are using it in a div or other element.

the only thing i know it will be visible is when you do it with background-color css.

```
<div style="background-color: #444444;">
...
</div>
```